# mvc razor foreach in view with sorted data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach

I'm new to MVC.

I want to implement data sorting on my html page.
I have a model that generated with this code:

```
public IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry> GetPercConfigEntries() 
{
    var results = from g in this.context.PercConfigEntry
                  where g.Key == "ConfigEntries"
                  select g;
    return results;
}
```

And a view:

```
@model IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry>
@foreach ( var config in Model )
{
   ...
}
```

This works. But when I add "orderby" to query like this:

```
public IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry> GetPercConfigEntries() 
{
    var results = from g in this.context.PercConfigEntry
                  where g.Key == "ConfigEntries"
                  orderby g.ConfigName
                  select g;
    return results;
}
```

it throws DataServiceQueryException on foreach.

What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with MVC or razor. My guess is it's an issue with your data service's query provider. If you call `ToList()` inside `GetPercConfigEntries()` the exception should occur there.

Comment: Try to call `ToList()` and then use order by like `results.OrderBy(x=> x.ConfigName)`

Comment: `var results = (from g in this.context.PercConfigEntry
                  where g.Key == "ConfigEntries"
                  select g).OrderBy(o => o.ConfigName);`

Comment: @christiandev That wouldn't be any different from what OP has already tried. Nilesh's suggestion is valid though, because it forces the un-ordered query to be evaluated *then* orders it on the client.

Comment: @christiandev I try this, but the same exception occur

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, you are right. I will try to fix this issue. Thank you!

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I was missing `.AsEnumerable();` before the `OrderBy`?

Comment: @christiandev `AsEnumerable`, `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc. would've worked. The key is to somehow change the result from an `IQueryable<T>` to an `IEnumerable<T>` before calling `OrderBy`. See the note on my answer for why that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has something do with your query provider; perhaps it simply doesn't support ordering. Without any further information, I'd recommend this:

```
public IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry> GetPercConfigEntries() 
{
    var results = 
        (from g in this.context.PercConfigEntry
         where g.Key == "ConfigEntries"
         select g)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(g => g.ConfigName);
    return results;
}
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<PercConfigEntry> GetPercConfigEntries() 
{
    var results = this.context.PercConfigEntry
        .Where(g => g.Key == "ConfigEntries")
        .AsEnumerable()
        .OrderBy(g => g.ConfigName);
    return results;
}
```

This forces the query to be executed on the provider *without* any ordering, then re-orders it on the client—in other words, the call to `AsEnumerable` effectively disconnects the result set from the query provider so that the `OrderBy` (or any subsequent methods) are evaluated on the client. This is probably not as efficient as allowing the provider to order it, but if the provider is doesn't support ordering, this is the only way to do it.